# How We can Avoid Using Extra work in Heap Sort Algorithm to find Second Largest Element in an array?

Tags: algorithm

Please also let me know the time complexity we can improve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heap sort takes `O(n Logn)` time for sorting n length heap. To obtain second largest element you should use heapify twice. Second number is what you looking for. it takes `2 * logn` (heapify) time. Complexity is `O(logn)`.

Answer (score 0):

If only the second largest values is required, then would a single pass bubble sort be quicker? Along the lines of:

```
biggest = array[0]

foreach element in array
  if element > biggest
    second_biggest = biggest
    biggest = element
  endif
next
```

which, if I get this right, is O(n).

But, estergones claims O(logn).

However, every value must be inspected at least once, and that's all that the above does so I can't see how the O(logn) is faster / does less work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If the largest element is in array[0], isn't the second largest in array[1] or array[2]? Since every node is greater or equal than it's two sons (and by transitivity, greater or equal than all its descendants).

Answer (score 0):

If one draws up a tournament-bracket (assume the number of teams is a power of two) and assumes that a better team will always beat an inferior one, then the best team will play against (and beat) lgN teams; the second-best team will always be one of those.  Note that finding the second-place team will always require lgN-1 comparisons, but if one wishes to improve the average performance of finding the third-best team, have the first two teams beaten by the best team play each other, have the winner of that play the third team, etc.

The third-best team will be one which was beaten by the second-best team (either before or after the second-best team was beaten by the best).  There will either be lgN or lgN-1 of these (most likely the former) so lgN-1 comparisons will suffice to find the third-best team.